# Program aborted inside select(). When can it happen?

Tags: select, sigabrt, abort

I am seeing this problem in a C program which after making connection to a
server calls select() with a timeout of 15 seconds to check if some data
is present from server. Although it works normally, but it crashes because
of signal 6 (SIGABRT) in select() sometimes. Can someone tell When can select() 
hit abort?

```
(gdb) bt
 #0  0x29309527 in select () from /usr/lib32/libc.so.6
 #1  0x2921530c in select () from /usr/lib32/libpthread.so.2
 #2  0x284ac0c0 in wait_until_writable (fd=48, timeout=15)
```

Sample Code for function `wait_until_writable()`:

```
int wait_until_writable(int fd, int timeout)
{
    int n, error;
    socklen_t len;
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set wfd;
    tv.tv_sec = timeout;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    error = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&wfd);
    FD_SET(fd,&wfd);
    // XXX An improvement would be to loop while errno=EINTR
    n = select(fd+1, NULL, &wfd, NULL, &tv);
    if (n > 0 && FD_ISSET((int)fd, &wfd)) {
        len = sizeof(error);
        if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (error) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide some sample code and more information to get an answer to this. Is select() your own function?

Answer (score 0):

A few cases when I have encountered a SIGABRT:

1. Assertion failure (invalid arguments to an internal function call, possibly due to a memory corruption bug).
2. An attempt to read from or write to a closed port (typically it should throw an I/O Error, though).
3. Binary data transfer via non-raw serial port, which is interrupted by a break character.